# Interesting error with Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

While trying to streamline my init.el, I decided to move some functionality out of an ugly cond tree. In order to move some decisions out of it, I built two helper functions:

```
(defun abstract-screen-width ()
  (cond ((eq 'x window-system) (x-display-pixel-width))
        ((eq 'ns window-system) (display-pixel-width))
        ))

(defun perfect-font-size (pixels)
  (cond ((eq 'x window-system) (cond ((<= pixels 1024) 100)
                                     ((<= pixels 1366) 110)
                                     ((> pixels 1366) 120)))
        ((eq 'ns window-system) (cond ((<= pixels 1024) 110)
                                      ((<= pixels 1280) 120)
                                      ((> pixels 1280) 140)))))
```

And they combine nicely and invoking them the way they were intended to be invoked works fine.

```
(perfect-font-size (abstract-screen-width))
130
```

The custom-set-faces invocation as it was works

```
(custom-set-faces
        '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil
                                :strike-through nil :overline nil
                                :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal
                                :height 130 :width normal
                                :family "IBM 3270"))))
        '(linum ((t (:inherit default :foreground "#777" :height 130)))))
```

but my "better" version

```
(custom-set-faces
        '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil
                                :strike-through nil :overline nil
                                :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal
                                :height (perfect-font-size (abstract-screen-width)) :width normal
                                :family "IBM 3270"))))
        '(linum ((t (:inherit default :foreground "#777" :height 120)))))
```

doesn't. It gives a "Default face height not absolute and positive" error. The source in faces.el and cus-face.el didn't help much. Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression

```
'(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil
                            :strike-through nil :overline nil
                            :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal
                            :height (perfect-font-size (abstract-screen-width)) :width normal
                            :family "IBM 3270"))))
```

is quoted in its entirety, i.e., `(perfect-font-size (abstract-screen-width))` won't be evaluated. Try backquote instead:

```
`(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil
                            :strike-through nil :overline nil
                            :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal
                            :height ,(perfect-font-size (abstract-screen-width)) :width normal
                            :family "IBM 3270"))))
```

(note the backtick and the comma). The error is just emacs way of telling you, that it had preferred a number where it got the list `(perfect-font-size (abstract-screen-width))`

Comment: BTW, you can just use `display-pixel-width` instead of your `abstract-screen-width`.

Comment: True. I am not sure why I used x-display-pixel-width, maybe display-pixel-width spitting an error in some distant past - this init.el is with me for more than a decade...